# The sleep function is not functioning as expected

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, stdout

The sleep function here is functioning *differently* on Windows and Linux.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
printf("Press 1 to apply for Password Change Request...\n");
                printf("\nPress any other key to try again");
                fflush(stdout);
                for(int j=0; j<2; j++)
                {
                        sleep(1);
                        printf("..");
                }
}
return 0;
```

On **Windows**, it is working as it is meant to, waiting for a second then printing `..` and then again waiting for a second and then printing `..`.
But on **Linux**, it is waiting for whole 2 seconds and then printing `....` altogether.

What should I do to fix it?

I am using **MinGW** on Windows.

Comment: stdout is line-buffered, so you'll have to either `fflush()` or add a `\n` (or change stdout to be unbuffered)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is probably due to the fact that `printf`s to *stdout* are buffered, meaning that the data sent through `printf` is actually printed under certain conditions. The default condition is that data is printed whenever a newline `'\n'` is sent (line buffering).

According to [setvbuf()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/setvbuf) documentation, three levels of buffering can be set:

- `_IOFBF`  full buffering
- `_IOLBF`  line buffering **(<-- this is the default value for stdout)**
- `_IONBF`  no buffering

so, calling

```
 setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

might be a way to solve the issue.

Anyway, the buffer can be flushed asynchronously with [fflush()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush):

```
fflush(stdout);
```

---

As an alternative to these solutions, you can simply add a `'\n'` to your prints

```
printf("..\n");
```

or use `puts()` function:

```
puts("..");
```